# How set a identity scaffolding item/page how initial page in asp.net MVC core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

I create a new mvc core with identity individual, then I override the login page:

```
new scaffolding item => identity => Login
```

In `Startup.cs` have a default 'index' page:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

however, this login page/view **HAVEN'T** a controller file in folder. e.g Controllers/AccountController.cs

Then, how I set login page how initial page in project?

Actual link auto-generated

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

I look lot links but cant find help.
https://stormpath.com/blog/routing-in-asp-net-core
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2
https://code-maze.com/routing-asp-net-core-mvc/

This link show something but it's the best way? Lot code lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56772526/4654957

Comment: Do you want to set the login page as the default start page ?

Comment: @XueliChen Exactly. But this page not have a controller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly it was solved. All work fine after add **AllowAreas**.

**ConfigureServices**

```
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.AllowAreas = true; //--working after add this line
        options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set below configuration in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Identity", "/Account/Login", "");
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Configure

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });
```

You could refer to : [How to make Login page as a default route in ASP .NET Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506419/how-to-make-login-page-as-a-default-route-in-asp-net-core-2-1)

Comment: Unfortunatly I had try this solutions without success and in this same page none have answer was marked like right. But now I already solved it. Thank you anyway

Answer (score -1):

Here is the official documentation on how to override default login process for .Net Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: and about my question?